# Excel Vba, when i want to access a table that was previously named by another vba, it doesn't work, but if i input the same name by hand it works

Tags: excel, vba, rename, excel-tables

I have a workbook, in this i use vba to create and rename tables. This is the Code i use:

```
tblName = "E" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "_" & Dropdown_Expander.Text & "_" & neuerTabellenname

rng.ListObject.Name = tblName
```

I also have another Workbook where i want to access the data in the tables. I use this Code to access that data:

```vb
Dim SourceWb As Workbook 
Dim SourceWs As Worksheet 
Dim SourceTb As ListObject 
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath) 
Set SourceWs = SourceWb.Sheets("Expanderliste 3") 
Set SourceTb = SourceWs.ListObjects(tblName)
```

When i execute this Sub i get an error message "Error '9'"

Thanks for any help in Advance

I compared the tblName in both Workbooks via Debug.Print as well as the Name of the table in Excel and they were all the same.

Also when i copy the table Name and change it to anything else for a short while, then paste the origional name back in, then the Sub works fine.

This seems like e weird error to me and i have no idea how to repair it. Can i possibly change the Naming process in order to make it work?

Comment: How is `SourceWs` defined?

Comment: @Ike  Dim SourceWb As Workbook  
Dim SourceWs As Worksheet   
Dim SourceTb As ListObject   
  
 Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)   
 Set SourceWs = SourceWb.Sheets("Expanderliste 3")   
 Set SourceTb = SourceWs.ListObjects("tblName")   I hope this helps

Comment: Error spotted: you have "tblName" with quotation marks --> so you use the string "tblName" and not the variable `tblName` --> remove the quotation marks and it will work. In your question you set SourceTb correct - but not according to the comment above.

Comment: i dont have tblName in quotation marks in my code, i just wrote that wrong in my comment. As i wrote in my origional question i use debug.print to check the naming, and this is the exact same name as the table in my excel sheet. Sorry for the confusion. I have now also tested this in a small excel Test-sheet and while i can select a hand generated table by directly using its name (first Set SourceTb) i cant with the vba generated one (second Set SourceTb)      Set SourceTb = SourceWs.ListObjects("Hallo")  
    Set SourceTb = SourceWs.ListObjects("E123456.xlsm_Expanderliste_1_Tabelle1")

Comment: Is there a way to upload the Test File, so anyone reading this can check for themselves?

Comment: you are referencing the worksheet to "Expanderliste **3**" - could this be the error?

Comment: Sadly no, the worksheet is the right one, could i just reference the table without the worksheet, so this is for sure no problem? If it matters i use Excel 2013 could this be the Problem?

Comment: There must be a typo somewhere ...

Comment: i finally found it, you were somewhat right. I created the Name for the table, but had a space in it. This was automatically transformed into a _ as you cant use a space in tablenames, but somehow it didnt create a functioning name for acces via vba.